# Best 2x 4GB RAM for a Thinkpad X200s

Tags: performance, memory, thinkpad

I need 2x 4GB RAM, a total of 8GB, in my upcoming Thinkpad X200s laptop.
Before buying, I would like your advice on which modules to choose.

I've been looking at Corsair's Value Select (P/N: CM3X4GSD1066) RAM, because in my experience they produce good RAM modules.

However, Corsair lists 7 clock cycles for their modules while Lenovo lists 5 clock cycles.

What do you think? Is Lenovo modules the best choice? Are they the fastest/most stable, or is it the Corsair modules? Or modules from a third vendor?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I searched google for "lenovo x200s 8gb memory" and the first in the results was a pdf-document from lenovo stating this in the footnotes.

"Footnotes: [1] Memory: Lenovo notebooks have a new 64-bit architecture. Notebooks with a Windows Vista 32-bit or previous Windows 32-bit operating system can support up to 2.5GB of addressable memory. Notebooks with a
Windows Vista 64-bit operating system can support up to 8GB of addressable memory. Maximum capacity may require purchase of optional component. Subject to availability of 4GB DIMMs. [2] Models with 4GB Memory: Total
accessible memory will be less and will vary depending on the system configuration. Maximum capacity may require purchase of optional component. Subject to availability of new 4GB DIMMs."

So its safe to buy 8GB of memory, If your OS can handle it. :)

-P

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Kingston website](http://www.ec.kingston.com/ecom/configurator_new/modelsinfo.asp?SysID=50139&mfr=Lenovo&model=ThinkPad+X200s+7462%2C7465%2C7466%2C7469%2C7470&search_type=&root=us&LinkBack=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.kingston.com&Sys=50139-Lenovo-ThinkPad+X200s+7462%2C7465%2C7466%2C7469%2C7470-xxx&distributor=0&submit1=Search) the maximum you can put in there is 4 GB

Comment: That is not true. Lenovo only "supports" 4GB I guess, but the hardware can take 8GB. It's used by many X200s users and other thinkpad users.

Comment: while it 'may' work, the only sound advice is to stick with the manufacturers recommendations. or discuss the matter at the thinkpad forum where some users are discussing the matter. obviously someone's got experience with 8 GB in the x200s. i'm pretty sure they'll gladly share their expertence with you. registration is free :) as for the Corsair Value Select memory modules, they're good bang for the buck (as the name suggests) but nothing to write home about when it comes to performance benchmarks. i'm using some CVS 2GB DDR2 myself.

Comment: But the Intel GM45 chipset supports 8GB RAM. So it would be odd if it does not support it?

Answer (score 0):

I would buy exactly what the other 8gb RAM x200 users are using.  If it is an officialy unsupported configuration, I would want to know exactly what others experiences were. I would do some research and buy the exact modules that other people have bought and have had success stories. It will help you reduce your chance of problems.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem: http://forum.thinkpads.com/viewtopic.php?f=43&t=78794&p=529265#p529265 - Anyway, I would like some advice on whats the best 4GB modules?

Comment: Yah, in that forum, people were asking what he was using several times, but he never said. I wonder if we can find anyone with concrete information.

Comment: But the Intel GM45 chipset supports 8GB RAM.

Comment: @Tommy You are correct, the chipset may support 8gb, but that doesn't mean all 4gb ram sticks will work in the machine. I have seen picky laptops (oddly enough, older thinkpads) before when buying max RAM upgrades.  We are not saying it won't work, it is just not a guarantee.

Comment: That is why we need to find someone who has put 8gb in a x200 and ask them/find out what exact RAM they bought. That way you can be pretty sure it will work.

Comment: I know - and I'm still trying to find someone. On the Thinkpad forum a few people has stated that it won't be a problem. Thats all I've got for now.

Answer (score 0):

Clock cycles don't really make much difference in real world use. Just buy the fastest speed of some name brand with a lifetime warranty and you'll be fine. If you really need more advice than that, go to [newegg](http://newegg.com), select the capacity and speed, and buy the one with the highest rated reviews.

Answer (score 0):

You should only be buying your RAM from Lenovo or an authorized reseller unless you want to risk potential complications with your warranty.  (It's unlikely to invalidate it unless it toasts the machine, but better safe than sorry...if you buy RAM with a valid Lenovo FRU it will carry the warranty of the laptop.)